# Help with IzPack - Creating Java and JNLP One Click Installations

Tags: java, installation, jnlp, izpack

I took the advice I've been given here to look at IzPack to create a JNLP based one click installation for computer illiterate clients who are using a Java desktop application I've created.

[Java Web Start Driven Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944144/java-web-start-driven-installation)

However, I can't seem to find my way around it.
I don't know where to begin and seems the online tutorials are basic "look at the examples" which are themselves pre compiled and not sourced.

I want to create a simple form - be it in JSP or the JNLP install app (preferably JSP and the JNLP should get arguments from the JSP that launches it).
Then when the users click Install, the program installs to the default directory of userappdata with no questions (except for the UAC).

But IzPack seems to be forcing me to use panels and stuff... Not sure I want all of that.

Or maybe....
Hmmm, writing this just gave me an idea, but I'd still like some feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach perhaps?

If all what you need is to allow the user invoke a JAR, then consider using JSmooth to wrap it in an exe file.    The exe file knows how to invoke java correctly and prompt the user to download if not present.

We also have used one-jar to wrap multiple jars in a single jar for exactly this purpose.